# Decomposition of cohomology group on $S^{n}$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

If we have decomposition of cohomology group on $S^{n}$ it looks like $H^{n}(S^{n})=H^{n}(S^{n})_{+}\oplus H^{n}(S^{n})_{-}$, where $H^{n}(S^{n})_{\pm}$ cohomology of invariant or anti-invariant $n$ form on $S^{n}$. Why one of $H^{n}(S^{n})_{\pm}$ are trival in dependence from $n$ odd or even?

Comment: That's because $H^n(S^n)$ is one dimensional. Is that what do want to ask in the precious question? If yes please delete that question.

Comment: Can you at least please fix the typos? The question is almost unreadable as it stands.

Comment: $H^{n}(S^{n})=R$Б, why one of classes invariant from the antipodal map form are trival

Comment: @johnstockes: If $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$ and $V$ is one dimensional, then either $V_1$ or $V_2$ is zero dimensional. Nothing to do with cohomology just linear algebra.

Answer (score 2):

As John points out, the answer to your first question has very little to do with cohomology.

As $H^n(S^n) = H^n_+(S^n) \oplus H^n_-(S^n)$, $\dim H^n(S^n) = \dim H^n_+(S^n) + \dim H^n_-(S^n)$ but $H^n(S^n) \cong \mathbb{R}$ as $S^n$ is a compact connected orientable $n$-dimensional manifold, so $\dim H^n(S^n) = 1$ so $\{\dim H^n_+(S^n), \dim H^n_-(S^n)\} = \{0, 1\}$.

As for the dependence on $n$, that does relate to cohomology.

What you need to know is that the antipodal map is orientation-preserving if and only if $n$ is odd (so it is orientation-reversing if and only if $n$ is even); this result is given as exercise $15$-$3$ in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, second edition. Another way of stating this is $\dim H^n_+(S^n) = 1$ if and only if $n$ is odd (so $\dim H^n_-(S^n) = 1$ if and only if $n$ is even). The equivalence follows because $H^n(S^n)$ is generated by the cohomology class of an orientation form.